# Html.CheckBoxfor() in for loop does not display checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, for-loop, checkbox, html-helper

Trying to iterate over a list in my view to display user preferences and if they're hecked or not.

Here is what I have for now in my view:

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.IdentityFields.FieldDefinitions.Count(); i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IdentityFields.FieldDefinitions[i].Id)
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IdentityFields.FieldDefinitions[i].IsActivated)
                @Html.Raw(Model.IdentityFields.FieldDefinitions[i].Name)
                @Html.Raw(Model.IdentityFields.FieldDefinitions[i].ApiKey)
                <br/>
            }
```

But checkboxes are not displayed.

[image]

Anyone can see if I'm doing something wrong here?
Thanks for helping !

EDIT :
Here is the html render :

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly is rendered into the html?

Comment: could be a CSS issue possibly, can you post the rendered HTML?

Comment: @zgood Just updated the original post. Thanks to both of you

Comment: Well it looks like the checkboxes are there, but if you can't see them then it must by a style issue. Can you look at the styles being applied to the checkboxes in the dev tools when you inspect element?

Comment: @zgood ok looking at the OP edit :  it seems you're pointing something here ahah

Comment: ya that `position: absolute; left: -10000px;` is putting your checkbox way left of the screen. This is usually the case when you use some kind of javascript checkbox plugin or are altering how you checkboxes look. If you don't want tis style messing with these checkboxes then maybe you could add a class to those checkboxes (like `new { @class = "unstyled" }` htmlAttributes object), then update that style defination above to `input[type=checkbox]:not(.unstyled) { ... }`. This will make it so it doesn't affect your checkboxes.

Comment: @zgood Thanks a lot, got my checkboxes on screen now ! :)